# Issue with redirect url in login with paypal feature

Tags: rest, next.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have gone to my profile and set up the URL
`http://127.0.0.1:3000/link-paypal`
I tried with localhost but then it kept saying try again (Not sure why) so now using 127...

I have gone to my dashboard and changed the URL to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/link-paypal`
I have removed their default URL `nativexo://paypalpay`

But still, when I click the button, I get the same error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you get your client id from an `env` file and you forget to put `NEXT_PUBLIC` to first of its name.

Try this:

1. Convert `CLIENT_ID` to the `NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID`
2. Call that var like this: `const NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID`